# How to search Google Groups for keywords

Tags: google-search, search, google-groups, keyword, usenet

I went to https://groups.google.com and searched for `boot ring seat`, looking for a specific Usenet message that I know has those three words in it. [No results.](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!search/boot$20ring$20seat) All right, I thought, maybe I'm misremembering the Usenet message. So I searched instead for `whenever` — there **must** be some Usenet messages with that word in it! But still [no results](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!search/whenever). (It says "Posts: 0, groups: 1354".) (These searches were done when not logged in to Google.)

What am I doing wrong? How do I search for Usenet posts by keywords in them?

---

Some notes (that you can skip) about the research I already did toward answering this question:

There *is* a help link on that search-result page, but there's nothing about searching listed there. The most promising subtopic is "Learn how to read and create posts", which doesn't actually answer this question.

I also did a Google Web search on `searching Google Groups Usenet`, but the top few results were unhelpful. The top one is from 2010, so I skipped it as likely [OBE](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/overtaken%20by%20events); the next promising one is [this SU post](//superuser.com/q/733111), which is about browsing a newsgroup rather than searching by keyword; etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to search Google Groups, you need simply to be signed in with Google Account otherwise you may encounter no results or various errors like:

> There was an error performing the search. Please try again later.
>   RELOAD

[image: 0]

---

Once you are logged in, you are able to search it as usual Google Search pages:

[image: 0]

---

And as regular Google Search, it supports all [**search operators**](https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/2466433?hl=en):

[image: 0]

Comment: Thank you very much! Works for me, too, so have a checkmark.

Answer (score 0):

I clicked on your first two links. One took me straight to the results page, which showed  over 46,000 results. The first link took me to the empty search box, where I manually entered your search terms and received the same results back.

So... something is different for you. I suggest you try a different browser, or try using the same browser after clearing cache and cookies. If that fails, run in Incognito or an equivalent browser mode that disables extensions, as an extension could be causing the problem.

Finally, if none of that works, I'd try simply doing the search on a different system, or a mobile phone.